# Cannot set property of userNm undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

After fetching value from DB, I am trying to put it in a variable, but when I do that it gives me error:

`core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'userNm' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'userNm' of undefined`

Here is my `ts` code:

```
userNm: string ='';

ngOnInit(){

   console.log("trying...");
   firebase.firestore().collection(`Students`)
   .where("authId", "==", this.userId) 
   .get()
   .then(querySnapshot => {
     querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
         console.log(doc.data().Name); // OK RESULT IN CONSOLE.LOG,NAME IS String in db.
         this.userNm=doc.data().Name;  // ERROR HERE
         console.log(this.userNm)
         console.log(doc.id, " ===> ", doc.data());
     });
   });
```

Screenshot of console and database:

[image]

[image]

Comment: user2828442: some of your questions have been edited recently, but your new questions are replicating the same errors. Your posts have a needy, begging quality, and suggests you think that displays of helplessness will cause people to pity your situation and/or feel coerced into the social obligation of assisting the less fortunate. This is not appropriate behaviour for a volunteer platform. The personal pronoun ("I") is also always an upper case, as you well know. Please have mercy on volunteer editors, who do not wish to clear up after you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` keyword in a Javascript `function()` refers to the scope of the function. To use member variables, use arrow function construct. You could try the following

```js
firebase.firestore().collection(`Students`)
  .where("authId", "==", this.userId) 
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {   // <-- Use arrow function here
      console.log(doc.data().Name);
      this.userNm = doc.data().Name;
      console.log(this.userNm)
      console.log(doc.id, " ===> ", doc.data());
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc)` this represent `anonymous` function `this`. use lambda
..

```
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{
         console.log(doc.data().Name); // OK RESULT IN CONSOLE.LOG,NAME IS String in db.
         this.userNm=doc.data().Name;  // ERROR HERE
         console.log(this.userNm)
         console.log(doc.id, " ===> ", doc.data());
     });
```